# Regex get port from host with multipe choises

Tags: regex

I need to get the **port** from url,
I use the following which works

https://regex101.com/r/yoBODY/1

`(?:([^@]*)@)?(.\[.+\]|([^:]+))(?:[:](\d+))?`

As im quite new to regex,
Am I missing something?

This is the inputs and from it I need to get the **port**

```
test:222
https://aaa.com:333

https://www.aaa.com:333
aaa.bbb.cccc:8000
```

im getting some URI/URL with port

if its OK please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For strings used as standalone strings you can use

```js
^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:([^@]*)@)?(\[[^][]+\]|([^:]+))(?::(\d+))?$
```

If you match these strings as lines in a multiline text, it is advisable to add `\n` and `\r` to the negated character classes to avoid overflowing on next line(s):

```js
^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:([^@\r\n]*)@)?(\[[^][\r\n]+\]|([^:\r\n]+))(?::(\d+))?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vFRvXR/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:https?:\/\/)?` - an optional `http://` or `https://`
- `(?:([^@]*)@)?` - an optional sequence of any zero or more chars other than `@` (captured into Group 1) and then a `@` char
- `(\[[^][]+\]|([^:]+))` - Group 2: either `[`, one or more chars other than `[` and `]` and then `]` or one or more chars other than `:` captured into Group 3
- `(?::(\d+))?` - an optional sequence of `:` and one or more digits captured into Group 4
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: thanks a lot, what does it mean "overflowing on next line(s)"  what does it mean for my case?  how it can be problmatic ?

Comment: @Alberto I don't know what your exact input looks like. If the strings are tested as whole strings against the regex, you do not need `\n`.

Comment: just one question , what is the purpose to \n\r , if I dont use it what could happen ?

Comment: @Alberto [This](https://regex101.com/r/vFRvXR/2) will be a match.